# Why does File Modified Time automatically increase by 2 seconds when copied to USB?

Tags: c#, windows, file, file-io

Okay, I'm having one of those weird moments trying to get the file modified time of documents in a USB drive. *Normally, I thought when a file is copied to a USB drive the file modified time doesn't change*. However, when I copy any file to a USB drive, I discover that the File modified time is increased by two.

On research however, I discovered other people have encountered this problem online but I have not seen any answer yet whatsoever except for [this article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) which says something about read and write time for fragmented files increasing on FAT partitions and does not clarify things for me.

I have not been able to verify whether this happens for all files. However, **what I want to know is any official sources of what exactly happens to the modified time when a file is copied to USB drive**. Will it be advisable for me to modify the file modified time in the code myself? *i.e. subtract two seconds*.

Comment: 1) how are you copying the files? 2) are you certain this doesn't happen when you copy to say a Network drive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Time Stamps Change When Copying From NTFS to FAT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127830):

> File time stamps on FAT drives are rounded to the nearest two seconds (even number) when the file is written to the drive. The file time stamps on NTFS drives are rounded to the nearest 100 nanoseconds when the file is written to the drive. Consequently, file time stamps on FAT drives always end with an even number of seconds, while file time stamps on NTFS drives can end with either even or odd number of seconds.
>
> When files are copied from NTFS drives to FAT drives, some file time stamp rounding has to occur; the file time stamp is rounded up to the next even second.

Comment: Thanks! Though it's actually difficult to understand how 10,000,000 nanoseconds ends up as two seconds... I'll do some code verifications for this.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the number 10,000,000 from. It is rounded up to the next even second (i.e., the next second that is a multiple of 2).

Comment: Wow, sorry that was like a buffer overwrite in my mind, I actually meant 100 nanoseconds but I was dividing 1 billion by 100 in error... I resorted to manipulating the file to ensure the dates are synchronised properly between the two media.

Comment: Rounding would maximally give an increase of one, though? :)

Comment: If the NTFS time was 12:00:00.000001 then rounding up to the next multiple of 2 seconds would be 12:00:02, which is an increase of 1.999999 seconds.

Comment: Ah, always rounded *up* instead of nearest. Forgot my reading apprehension glasses there ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that this has to do with USB, but very likely it has to do with the FAT filesystem (which has 2sec granularity for it's last-modified timestamp).

Have you verified that it's actually increasing this timestamp by 2sec, or are you copying to the external drive very fast after file creation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a generic solution, but I resolved my problem as follows:

1. First, I'd get and store the last modified time and check if it ends with an odd no. If it does, I change it to an even one, i.e. *increase it by one on the NTFS disk*.
2. I copy it to the USB drive and set the last modified time to the datetime gotten above (which is even).